# Need to scrape information from a webpage with a "show more" button, any recommendations?

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Currently developing a "crawler" for educational reasons,

Everything is working fine, i can extract url's & information & save it in a json file, everything is all fine and dandy... EXCEPT

the page has a "load more" button that i NEED to interact with in order for the crawler to continue looking for more urls.

This is where i could use you amazing guys & girls!

Any recommendations on how to do this?

I would like to interact with the "load more" button and re-send the HTML information to my crawler.

Would really, appreciate any amount of help from you guys!

Website: http://virali.se/photo/gallery/

bit of example code for finding business names:

```
def base_spider(self, max_pages, max_CIDS):
    url = "http://virali.se/photo/gallery/photog/"  # Input URL

    for pages in range(0, max_pages):
        source_code = requests.get(url)  # gets the source_code from the URL
        plain_text = source_code.text  # Pure text transform for BeautifulSoup
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")  # Use HTML parser to read the plain_text var
    for article in soup.find_all("article"):
            business_name_pattern = re.compile(r"<h1>(.*?)</?h1>")
            business_name_raw = str(re.findall(business_name_pattern, str(article)))
            business_name_clean = re.sub("[\[\]\'\"]", "", business_name_raw)
            self.myprint(business_name_clean)  # custom print function for weird chars
```

This code is only looking for the business names, but of course, it is going to run out of business names to search for if the "show more results" button on the url is not interacted with.

Comment: PS: "Scrapy" framework is not an option, i'm currently using Beautifulsoup, regex's & requests

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the site you are scraping and what you've tried (code) so far?

Comment: Haven't tried much in terms of interacting with the page, just some basic BeautifulSoup & Regex, code is not going to help here i'm afraid :p

Comment: You need to show us the site you're interacting with and your code or we cannot help you, because we are not magical mind readers.  In particular, there are different ways the "load more" button may work that would have a bearing on our answers.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, added some more clarity into my question.

Comment: I think @NickKenens is talking about scrapping a javascript powered website. In this case you will need to use a little be more complex scraping setup, a scaper that use a browser.

Comment: That's exactly what i mean @amirouche, thanks for the clarification! what kind of browser would you recommend, something like mechanize?

Comment: Just figure out what's doing that "load more" button. Is it getting more info using ajax? Is it executing some javascript?

Comment: @curro it's running a javascript function with the "onclick=" attribute

Comment: You should keep digging into that javascript/html code in order to know if the "load more" info is already in the html code (then just parse it) or if it comes from another url (then goes to that new url and parse info).

Comment: @NickKenens Selenium is the standard. You can +1 helpful commens ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the site with a developer tool (I used Chrome) then you can see that an XHR post request is fired when you click the "Show more results" button.

In this case you can emulate this request to gather the data:

```
with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.post("http://virali.se/photo/gallery/search", data={'start':0})
    print(response.content)
```

The "magic" is in the `data` parameter of the `session.post`: it is the required argument to load the images from this offset. In the example above `0` is the first bunch of images you see per default on the site.

And you can parse `response.content` with BeautifulSoup.

I hope this helps you get started, although the example uses Python 3 but it can be solved with Python 2 too in the same manner (without using the `with` construct).

Comment: Very interesting approach my friend! I use selenium now to do all the javascript interaction, i just execute scripts on the page now :p

Comment: Well, this is the action if you do not want to use Selenium because it has its problems too. I like this way more than an extra tool to emulate a browser because sometimes it does not work as I want to :)