# Beautifoul soup scraping trip advisor partial_entry

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Hi  would like to create a program for scrapping Trip advisor comment but I have only a part of the comment. I would add the full comment that is behind the link "more"

[image: Capture of link]

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata =BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

for i in range(5,200,5):
    soup = make_soup("https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Hotel_Review-g187497-d7142609-Reviews-or"+str(i))
    for item in soup.findAll('p', {'class' : 'partial_entry'}) :
        liste_noms.append(item.getText())
        print(item.text)
```

Comment: The way the More button works is via JS. onclick="ta.prwidgets.call('handlers.clickExpand',event,this);" 
BeautifulSoup isn't suited to make such requests. I mostly use Selenium, however, I'm sure there are other ways to do this, hopefully, someone else can help you but Selenium is my way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I found another subject on the forum which talk about the same topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246714/need-to-scrape-information-from-a-webpage-with-a-show-more-button-any-recomme . I will try to apply theirs methods in my script first, then if it's too complicated I will use Selenium